# bluetooth LE MVC architecture

Tags: model-view-controller, architecture, bluetooth-lowenergy, structure

I am developing an Android app that connects to a device and send command to get its information such as version number.

I am building it using the Bluetooth LE sample code which has DeviceScanActivity, DeviceControlActivity and BluetoothLeService.

I am trying to understand the structure so I can make the code separate from GUI and low level operations.

1. Is DeviceControlActivity equivalent to View + Control in MVC model? Is BluetoothLeService equivalent to Model?
2. I want to have a class separate from GUI that has functions to operate the device. eg. contains a function called getVersion(). Does this class belong to Model as well? How should I implement this class along with BluetoothLeService?

Basically I want to have a hierarchy as UI->a Class of functions->Bluetooth rx & tx.

Answer (score 0):

I created an instance of the class of functions and I derived command data from it.
Then I sent this command to BluetoothLeService.